# MVC Error Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gac

Server Error in '/' Application.

---

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll' or from assembly 'C:\Projects\Samples\JQuery\bin\JQuery.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" 
Line 2:             Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" 
Line 3:             EnableTheming="true" %>

Source File: /Views/Shared/Site.Master    Line: 1

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4918; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4918

Maybe I am just confused as to why this would all of a sudden popup on me.  I’ve been working on this test app for 2 days now and just hit F5 and wham…

-kb

Comment: google is your friend, check this link http://www.alphapapahotel.com/system-web-mvc-viewmasterpage-parser-erro/aspnet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temp directory used for builds was holding onto another assembly.  After deleting the temp build directory and rebuilding this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps you, in the solution explorer, right click on the solution file/ properties/configuration properties, and check the bluid option for each project in your solution, then clic on the ok button and recompile all the solution,